# NoMethodError: undefined method `symbolize_keys' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, ruby-on-rails-5, capistrano3

while deploying rails application to production server.
**capistrano unable to load following file from confing**

```
server_options = YAML.load_file(File.join(Rails.root, "config", "server.yml"))[Rails.env].symbolize_keys
```

I have created the following files manually on server

- config/database.yml
- config/aws.yml
- config/cable.yml
- config/email.yml
- config/secrets.yml
- config/server.yml
- config/application.yml

> Because these are in .gitignore

```
  # add sensitive files to .gitignore
  config/database.yml
  config/aws.yml
  config/cable.yml
  config/email.yml
  config/secrets.yml
  config/server.yml
  config/application.yml
```

> Here is the symlinking part of capistrano in deploy.rb

## files we want symlinking to specific entries in shared.

```
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml config/aws.yml config/cable.yml config/email.yml config/secrets.yml config/server.yml config/application.yml}

# dirs we want symlinking to shared
set :linked_dirs, %w{log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system public/pdf public/excel public/img}

# what specs should be run before deployment is allowed to
# continue, see lib/capistrano/tasks/run_tests.cap
set :tests, []

# which config files should be copied by deploy:setup_config
# see documentation in lib/capistrano/tasks/setup_config.cap
# for details of operations
set(:config_files, %w(
  nginx.conf
  database.example.yml
  aws.example.yml
  cable.example.yml
  email.example.yml
  secrets.example.yml
  server.example.yml
  application.example.yml
  log_rotation
  unicorn.rb
  unicorn_init.sh
))

# which config files should be made executable after copying
# by deploy:setup_config
set(:executable_config_files, %w(
  unicorn_init.sh
))

# files which need to be symlinked to other parts of the
# filesystem. For example nginx virtualhosts, log rotation
# init scripts etc.
set(:symlinks, [
  {
    source: "nginx.conf",
    link: "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/{{full_app_name}}"
  },
  {
    source: "unicorn_init.sh",
    link: "/etc/init.d/unicorn_{{full_app_name}}"
  },
  {
    source: "log_rotation",
   link: "/etc/logrotate.d/{{full_app_name}}"
  }
])
```

Now upon deploying  **cap staging deploy**

> Full trace by **cap staging deploy --trace**

```
  deploy:assets:precompile
        01 RBENV_ROOT=/home/centos/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.4.0 /home/centos/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile
        01 rake aborted!
        01 NoMethodError: undefined method `symbolize_keys' for nil:NilClass
        01 /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/releases/20190125070939/config/environments/production.rb:88:in `block in <top (r…
        01 /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:209:in `insta…
        01 /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:209:in `confi…
        01 /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/releases/20190125070939/config/environments/production.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        01 /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.1/lib/active_support/dependenci…
        01 /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.1/lib/active_support/dependenci…
        01 /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.1/lib/active_support/dependenci…
        01 /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.1/lib/active_support/dependenci…
        01 /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:600:in `block …
        01 /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:599:in `each'
        01 /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:599:in `block …
        01 /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `…
        01 /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `…
        01 /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `…
        01 /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `…
        01 /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `…
        01 /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `…
        01 /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `i…
        01 /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/releases/20190125070939/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        01 /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `r…
        01 /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `r…
        01 /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:448:in `b…
        01 /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:6…
        01 /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
        01 /home/centos/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
        01 /home/centos/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
        01 Tasks: TOP => environment
        01 (See full trace by running task with --trace)
  cap aborted!
  SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as centos@54.84.214.65: rake exit status: 1
  rake stdout: rake aborted!
  NoMethodError: undefined method `symbolize_keys' for nil:NilClass
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/releases/20190125070939/config/environments/production.rb:88:in `block in <top (required)>'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:209:in `instance_eval'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:209:in `configure'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/releases/20190125070939/config/environments/production.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:600:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:599:in `each'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:599:in `block in <class:Engine>'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/releases/20190125070939/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:448:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in define'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/centos/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
  /home/centos/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
  Tasks: TOP => environment
  (See full trace by running task with --trace)
  rake stderr: Nothing written
  /home/developer/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute'
  /home/developer/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in execute'

  Caused by:
  SSHKit::Command::Failed: rake exit status: 1
  rake stdout: rake aborted!
  NoMethodError: undefined method `symbolize_keys' for nil:NilClass
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/releases/20190125070939/config/environments/production.rb:88:in `block in <top (required)>'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:209:in `instance_eval'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:209:in `configure'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/releases/20190125070939/config/environments/production.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:600:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:599:in `each'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:599:in `block in <class:Engine>'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/releases/20190125070939/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:448:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in define'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/centos/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
  /home/centos/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
  Tasks: TOP => environment
  (See full trace by running task with --trace)
  rake stderr: Nothing written
  /home/developer/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.0/lib/sshkit/command.rb:99:in `exit_status='
  /home/developer/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:169:in `execute_command'
  /home/developer/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:145:in `block in create_command_and_execute'
  /home/developer/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:145:in `tap'
  /home/developer/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:145:in `create_command_and_execute'
  /home/developer/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:78:in `execute'
  /home/developer/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capistrano-rails-1.1.8/lib/capistrano/tasks/assets.rake:69:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'
  /home/developer/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:97:in `with'
  /home/developer/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capistrano-rails-1.1.8/lib/capistrano/tasks/assets.rake:68:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
  /home/developer/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:89:in `within'
  /home/developer/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capistrano-rails-1.1.8/lib/capistrano/tasks/assets.rake:67:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
  /home/developer/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `instance_exec'
  /home/developer/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `run'
  /home/developer/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
  Tasks: TOP => deploy:assets:precompile
  The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as centos@54.84.214.65: rake exit status: 1
  rake stdout: rake aborted!
  NoMethodError: undefined method `symbolize_keys' for nil:NilClass
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/releases/20190125070939/config/environments/production.rb:88:in `block in <top (required)>'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:209:in `instance_eval'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:209:in `configure'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/releases/20190125070939/config/environments/production.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:600:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:599:in `each'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:599:in `block in <class:Engine>'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/releases/20190125070939/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:448:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in define'
  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/centos/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
  /home/centos/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
  Tasks: TOP => environment
  (See full trace by running task with --trace)
  rake stderr: Nothing written
  ** Invoke deploy:failed (first_time)
  ** Execute deploy:failed


  ** DEPLOY FAILED
  ** Refer to log/capistrano.log for details. Here are the last 20 lines:


  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:600:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'

  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:599:in `each'

  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:599:in `block in <class:Engine>'

  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'

  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'

  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'

  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'

  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'

  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'

  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'

  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/releases/20190125070939/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'

  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require'

  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'

  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:448:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'

  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in define'

  /home/centos/apps/expedite_pm_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'

  /home/centos/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/bundle:22:in `load'

  /home/centos/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
```

Comment: when I load this file from local server's console it get loaded without any error.

Comment: Try with this: `YAML.safe_load(File.read(Rails.root.join('config', 'server.yml')))`, and in the case it doesn't work, try this: `YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config', 'server.yml'))['your_key_from_server_yml'].map(&:to_sym)`

Comment: thanks for the help, surely will give it try.